# звонить в школу vs звонить школе?

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слова, глаголы

I found the following sentence:

> Моя мама позвонила в школу.

According to my dictionary, звонить/позвонить takes either dative, or в + accusative.

However, I'm not sure when to use it over the other. How can I decide which one to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Звонить + дат.* means "to call someone". The object has to be animate.

> Я отдельно живу от отца, поэтому можешь звонить мне в любое время. *[Андрей Геласимов. Жанна (2001)]*

*Звонить + куда?* means "to call something (like a place)". The object has to answer the question "to what place? / where to? / whither?" It can be a noun preceded by the preposition *в* or *на*, or an adverb like *домой, наверх*.

> Жена жалуется, что звонят домой в любое время суток. *[Виктор Лихачев. Наши интервью // «Встреча» (Дубна), 2003.06.18]*
>
> Ремонтники, в свою очередь, только осматривают поезда и, найдя неполадку, не чинят ее, а звонят на завод за консультацией. *[Андрей Веселов. Поезд дальше не пойдет // «Русский репортер», 2013]*
>
> Время от времени Таня звонила в Москву, Витальке и отцу. *[Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого [Путешествие в седьмую сторону света] // «Новый Мир», 2000]*
>
> … ей пришлось звонить наверх и объясняться. *[Ольга Славникова. Бессмертный. Повесть о настоящем человеке (2000-2001) // «Октябрь», 2001]*

Comment: Other usage variants - утром звонили в колокола, он не любил звонить по телефону.